# How would I recreate this angled linear gradient in CSS for IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, css-filters

I have create a linear gradient that is angled lines with some extra spacing between them. This works in all modern browsers. But with IE9, I know I'd need to use a filter but am not sure how.

The CSS:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, red, red 6px, yellow 7px, yellow 8px );
```